# why do java local variables not have a default value?

Tags: java, programming-languages

Why is it that in Java class fields are initialized to null/0 and local variables are not?  Is there a reason for this language design choice?

Comment: While this is an interesting question, I'm not sure that you'll be able to get a definitive answer from anyone here at Stack Overflow.  You'd probably have to ask the language designers.

Comment: The reason that java local variables do not have a default value is because in the design of the java language it was decided that local variables do not have default values.